# Difference between Parallel.ForEach and ParallelEnumerable.ForAll

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, plinq

I have a collection of Model classes and I wan't to Map each class individually to View Model classes.

I can use `Parallel.ForEach` or `ParallelEnumerable.ForAll`, so what is the difference between the 2, if any?

I couldn't find anything on MSDN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I can use Parallel.ForEach or ParallelEnumerable.ForAll, so what is the difference between the 2, if any?

`Parallel.ForEach` is the equivelent to using `foreach` in normal code.

The `ParallelEnumerable.ForAll` method is effectively the equivelent to [`List<T>.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx).

Both will perform and work similarly, though the `ForAll` method requires you to be using PLINQ already, as you need a `ParallelEnumerable`.  `Parallel.ForEach` works directly off any `IEnumerable<T>`.

In general, I tend to prefer `Parallel.ForEach`, as the sole purpose of `ForAll` is to cause side effects.  There are some disadvantages to this, as [described in detail by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Comment: uh huh, so basically they are pretty much identical except for the fact that `ParallelEnumerable` requires an actual `ParallelEnumerable`.

Comment: I agree with the side-effect part, but I want to map items in parallel in this case I think it is valid to do so. Correct me if I am wrong, but `Parallel.ForEach` does indeed execute iterations in parallel...right?

Comment: @StanR. Yes, it does.  "Mapping" suggests a PLINQ Select() clause, not a `ForAll()` statement, though, as Select is effectively a mapping operation...

Comment: I think I am wasting time here, since i would have to collect all my mapped items back into a concurrent list probably not worth it for a small list in terms of context switching.

Comment: @StanR. Depends on the # and what you're doing with the mapping - if you're building the queue, and processing is required, you can construct it directly from the PLINQ.Select() results via http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267303.aspx

Comment: i would say that if each mapping procedure took a decent amount of time, it would make sense. but this is simple property mappings on less than 1000 items. pure overkill in my opinion :) thanks for the linq, i need to step up my PLINQ game.